# Mozilla Firefox doesn't erase all the cookies parameter

Tags: firefox

I use Ubuntu Studo 20.04.4 LTS (64 bit Computer) and Mozilla Firefox 97.0.

Last week I've got a problem that I had some time ago: the cookies panel isn't erase at all. I can see some 35 KB of something which is not erased. It is supposed that we get a 0 KB data in this parameter (please, see the attached image).

[image: 35KB of Cookies not erased]

If I click on the "Erase now" button, I still get that 35 KB of something.

Why? I don't have any clue.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!!!

HOW TO FULL ERASE THE CACHE TEMP FOLDER OF MOZILLA FIREFOX WEB BROWSER

1. Open a TERMINAL session.
2. Write:
   sudo -i (the system will prompt for your SuperUser keyword)
3. Write:
   Thunar (or any other Files Manager you use)
4. At "ROOT" primary folder and look for the following folder:
   /home/"user name"/.cache/mozilla/firefox/
5. Eliminate all files and directories you can see there.
6. Close the TERMINAL session.

That's all, folks!!!